# Spawned Unity UI Grid Layout child object is not correct size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I am using unity grid layout component but not working correctly.

I am using unity grid layout component [grid layout values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVaXA.png). When I drag and drop my prefab as a child of grid layout object is perfectly normal working: [normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYxAy.png) but when I use this code for spawning, starts not fitting: [not size correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4dK0.png)

**Code:**

```
GameObject temp = Instantiate(myprefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
temp.transform.SetParent(mylayout.transform);
```

But when I setting game view full screen and running code its change again its changing with game screen size [different size same code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xql6l.png).

[Canvas Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCsfQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo I can use [LayoutBuilder](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate.html) to force a rebuild after adding your grid element.
Pas the parent recttransform as parameter.